# Sums of ratios of a set’s sums to its products

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, functions

Let $S = \{1, 2, 3, ..., 8\}$.
Let $A \subseteq S$ and $A \neq \varnothing$.

$F(X) = \text{sum of all elements in } X.$

$G(X) = \text{product of all elements in }X$.

Calculate $\left\lfloor{\sum_{A ⊆ S}^\  \frac {F(A)} {G(A)}}\right\rfloor$.

My approach was looking for a pattern, so I calculated the first three terms and found out the sum could be $\frac {N^3-(N-1)^2} N$. Can someone help me finding the real solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OP asked about $S=\{1, 2, \dots, 8\},$ but I assume what's really meant is $S=\{1, 2, \dots, n-1\}$ for any $n.$  (The final expression turns out to be simpler with $n-1$ here rather than $n.)$

I'll prove that $$\sum_{A ⊆ \{1, 2, \dots, n-1\}}\frac {F(A)} {G(A)} = n(n-H_n),$$
where $H_n$ is the $n^\text{th}$ harmonic number; $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1 k.$

Using the asymptotic expansion of $H_n,$ you can see that a very close approximation to $n(n-H_n)$ is $$n^2-n\ln n-n\gamma -\frac12,$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

OP asked about the floor of this value, but there probably isn't a closed form specifically for that integer, besides simply taking the floor of the harmonic-number formula above.

---

I prefer writing $\sum A$ and $\prod A$ instead of $F(A)$ and $G(A),$ respectively.

We'll follow the usual conventions that $\sum\emptyset=0$ and $\prod\emptyset=1.$

Also, in one place in the question, OP suggests requiring $A\subseteq S$ to be non-empty, but that doesn't change the value of the sum, since $
\frac{\sum\emptyset}{\prod\emptyset}=0.$

---

First we'll calculate $$P_n = \sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}} \frac1{ \prod A}.$$

Note that $P_0=1$ and, for $n>0,$ $$\begin{align}
P_n &= \sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}} \frac1{ \prod A}
\\
&= \sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\},\, n\notin A} \frac1{ \prod A}
+ \sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\},\, n\in A} \frac1{ \prod A}
\\
&= \sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n-1\}} \frac1{ \prod A}
+ \sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n-1\}} \frac1{ \prod (A\cup\{n\})}
\\
&= P_{n-1} + \sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n-1\}} \frac1{n \prod A}
\\
&= P_{n-1} + \frac1{n} \sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n-1\}}\frac1{\prod A}
\\
&= P_{n-1} + \frac1{n} P_{n-1}
\\
&= (1+\frac1{n}) P_{n-1},
\end{align}$$

and it follows easily by induction that $$P_n=n+1$$
for all $n \ge 0.$

$$ $$

Next we'll find a recurrence relation for $$D_n=\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}} \frac{\sum A}{\prod A}.$$

We have $D_0=0$ and, for $n>0,$
$$\begin{align}
D_n &=\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}} \frac{\sum A}{\prod A}
\\
&=\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\},\, n\notin A} \frac{\sum A}{\prod A}+\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\},\, n\in A} \frac{\sum A}{\prod A}
\\
&=\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n-1\}} \frac{\sum A}{\prod A}+\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n-1\}} \frac{\sum (A\cup\{n\})}{\prod (A\cup\{n\})}
\\
&=D_{n-1}+\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n-1\}} \frac{n+\sum A}{n \prod A}
\\
&=D_{n-1}+\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n-1\}} \frac{n}{n \prod A}
+\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n-1\}} \frac{\sum A}{n \prod A}
\\
&=D_{n-1}+\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n-1\}} \frac1{ \prod A}
+\frac1{n}D_{n-1}
\\
&=(1+\frac1{n})D_{n-1}+\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n-1\}} \frac1{ \prod A}
\\
&=(1+\frac1{n})D_{n-1}+P_{n-1}
\\
&=\frac{n+1}{n}D_{n-1}+n.
\end{align}$$

This recurrence relation can be solved in terms of the harmonic numbers $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1 k,$ as follows:

$$D_{n-1}=n(n-H_n)$$

for $n \ge 1.$

This can shown by induction, completing the proof of the desired formula.

Comment: A more direct approach for $P_n$ is $$\sum_A \prod_{i\in A}\frac{1}{i}=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{i}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{i+1}{i}=n+1$$

Comment: @RobPratt Nice approach -- thanks.

Comment: Beautiful, great derivation.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a program to generate the values of this sum over all sets of the form $\{1, 2, 3,  \ldots, n\}$ for $0 \le n \lt 25$ and got back this sequence:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
0,   & 1,   & 3,   & 7,   & 13, \\
21,  & 30,  & 42,  & 55,  & 70, \\
87,  & 106, & 127, & 150, & 175,\\
201, & 230, & 261, & 293, & 328,\\
364, & 402, & 443, & 485, & 529
\end{array}$$

These values don't match the formula you came up with for the first few terms. Moreover, I'm not sure this is a known sequence of numbers; it doesn't appear in the OEIS. I also tried looking up the first differences of the terms in the sequence, but that also isn't in the OEIS anywhere either.

The closest sequence I found to the sequence of values you're looking for is [this one](https://oeis.org/A025721), which it closely tracks but doesn't quite match. Curiously, that sequence seems to have nothing whatsoever to do with sets or set theory.

Here's the code I wrote, both for reference and in case there are any bugs. :-)

````
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

/* Given a list of numbers, returns their sum. */
double sumOf(const vector<int>& v) {
    return accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0);
}

/* Given a list of numbers, returns their product. */
double productOf(const vector<int>& v) {
    return accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 1.0, multiplies<double>()); 
}

int main() {
    /* List of the sets we've generated so far. Start with the empty set. */
    vector<vector<int>> sets = {{}};
    
    for (int n = 1; n <= 20; n++) {
        /* Compute the sum. */
        double total = 0;        
        for (const auto& set: sets) {
            total += sumOf(set) / productOf(set);
        }
        
        /* Cast to int to take the floor. */
        cout << int(total) << ", " << flush;
        
        /* Expand the set to form the next power set. Do this by taking each
         * existing set and creating a new set that includes the value of n.
         */
        auto size = sets.size();
        for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            auto set = sets[j];
            set.push_back(n);
            sets.push_back(set);
        }
    }
}
```
````